# Disable date before today in calendar android

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am trying to disable date before today from my calendar but the date is not disabled. This is my code.

```
DateTime dateTime = this.datetimeList.get(position);

if (dateTime.isBefore(getToday())) {
                cellView.setBackgroundResource(resources
                        .getColor(com.caldroid.R.color.caldroid_sky_blue));

tv1.setEnabled(false);
            tv1.setTextColor(convertView.getResources().getColor(R.color.caldroid_white));
            }
```

Is it the right way to compare date ?

Comment: what's wrong whit isBefore?

Comment: well currently you just change the backgroundresouce... you may want to disable your date field or whatever you mean...

Comment: Not sure if your code works or not, it does not really say in the question. Is DateTime the Joda class? Maybe you could use the regular [Calender](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and `before()` method. Also as @OschtärEi pointed out you don't really disable anything, just change color.

Comment: ok i've updated my code. and @Qben it is not getting into the condition

Comment: If it's not entering the `if` I can only assume `dateTime` is actually today or in the future. I also assume that `getToday()` return the correct value and that `isBefore()` works as expected.

Comment: dateTime is the dateTime of the calender cell

Comment: sorry but you have to give us conrcete values for `dateTime` and `getToday()`... else we can only guess right know

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (removeTime(questionDate).equals(removeTime(today)) 
  ...

public Date removeTime(Date date) {    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);  
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  
    return cal.getTime(); 
}
```